# Kony Studio importing android .so system library

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

We are sending a library (.so) file to a client and they are using the Kony framework.  We are using LoadLibrary call which seems to only have the lib/ folder in their search path.  Is there a way for KonyOne to pick up the .so files?

Thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with Kony studio, can some one help me in this

Answer (score 0):

We can import .so files in kony one (kony studio) for android. in two simple ways.

**1-** Go to Navigator window, select the app, go to resources folder, in resources folder, you can find customlibs folder with jsSrc, jsXml and lib. 
In lib folder, there is an android folder. we can copy all .so files into this android folder.

**2-** If you unable to find customlibs folder, you can go to workspace, /workspace/temp/app/build/luaandroid/dist/app/libs.
There we can copy the .so files along with folders like armeabi or armeabi-v7a.

**Important Note:** while copying the .so files(like libskonyjsvm.so), better to keep the default .so files in the mentioned folders.